# Azure api app provisioning failed

Tags: api, azure, provisioning, azure-api-apps

I am creating an Azure API APP, 
VS2013, new project (API APP, preview), installed new azure sdk for vs 2013.

Creation was successful, build just fine. tested the app locally, good.
now I right click on project and then click publish as suggested here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-dotnet-deploy-api-app/
I get the following error in my AzureApp Service Activity window in VS:

> Registering the Azure resource provider
>   Creating the Azure resource group HammerHeadResourceGroup
>   Creating the API App HammerHeadApiApp
>   Exception: Deployment failed for /subscriptions/cd0dd0a0-7d5c-4fd5-9c4a-c3a823bf94f4/resourceGroups/HammerHeadResourceGroup/deployments/ema_apiapp_deployment
>   Error in /subscriptions/cd0dd0a0-7d5c-4fd5-9c4a-c3a823bf94f4/resourcegroups/HammerHeadResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/Microsoft-ApiApp9ea2693c4a6148f591cc32cfdb14be1f/siteextensions/Microsoft.ApiApp: none
>   Error in /subscriptions/cd0dd0a0-7d5c-4fd5-9c4a-c3a823bf94f4/resourcegroups/HammerHeadResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ApiAppDeployment_bd094637090e46749d80a82bf9f9db6d: ResourceDeploymentFailure: The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.
>   Azure API App provisioning failed

Please advice.

Comment: Have you tried creating an API app via http://portal.azure.com? And if so, did that work successfully using the same Azure subscription?

Comment: Agreed. I had similar issues and found that using the portal worked.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing publishing from VS. When I went into the Resource Group on the azure portal and clicked deployments I could see the real error message which was "Location 'Central US' is not accepting creation of new Windows Azure SQL Database servers at this time."

[image: deployments error]

Answer (score 1):

Thank You, 
While I am publishing from VS, I am also creating a Resource group and service app plan, which failed. But then I used the Default resource group and the respective service app, then it worked.